# spark ml - how to verify Bias, Variance, Learning Curve

Tags: apache-spark-mllib

I am using spark.ml library (scala language) and using Random Forest Classifier. The ML model is created using Pipiline & CrossValidation.
In order to verify the model, i would like to check the Bias, Variance and the Learning Curve of my model.
Please let me know how this can be done using spark.ml library.